# Why is 'Middlesbrough' so spelled?

Tags: orthography, proper-nouns

Why is the English town of ***Middlesbrough*** so spelled, and why is the first 'o' of *borough* missing, as it is not with such as *Scarborough*, *Peterborough*, *Knaresborough*, etc.

I note that there are towns called ***Middlesborough*** in the United States which retain a first 'o'. But my spell checker does not like them!

Comment: Probably reflects a syncopated pronunciation or metathesis of *burh*.

Comment: Because . . . chaos.

Comment: They ran out of space on the sign.

Comment: @HotLicks Shouldn’t that have made it _Middlesboroug_?

Comment: The name of Middlesbrough was formerly written variously in old documents as Midelesburg, Middlesburc, Midlesburch, Midlesbured (probably the d having been a slip of the pen and intended for h). http://www.genuki.org.uk/big/eng/YKS/NRY/Middlesbrough/Middlesbrough90.html

Comment: @Josh61 So why didn't it become a *...borough* like *Peterborough*?

Comment: I don't think you will find a definite answer, anyway  (according to an anecdote)  it may just be  that Middlesbrough was misspelled when it was given its charter in 1853 and that this version stuck. My previous post shows that the name had many different spellings in past centuries and a spelling error might just be the case.

Comment: Somebody probably said *"we can't spell it Middlesborough; nobody pronounces the first 'o', so let's take it out"*. Despite the examples of Worcester, Greenwich, Edinburgh, Reading, and all the other places in the U.K. where the pronunciation is totally different from the spelling.

Comment: I think the *real* question is "why is Peterborough not spelled Peterbrough?" you will be hard-pressed to find an Englishman that pronounces the o.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Well I certainly pronounce the first o in Peterborough, as I do in the case of Attleborough. I think you will find that Peterborough people do too. Had you chosen places further north such as Scarborough or Knaresborough to make that point you may have had a stronger case.. But the south of England equivalent is often *...bury* as in *Aylesbury*.

Comment: Maybe it's a North-South dialect spelling thing; Fraserburgh, Edinburgh, Middlesbrough, Peterborough, Wellingborough, Newbury, Canterbury, Salisbury. Oddly I can't think of any West coast 'burgh/brough/borough' except when we get to 'bury' then there's quite a few westerly ones including Shrewsbury which is as north as Peterborough.

Comment: @Frank For what it is worth, this note appears at the end of the OED's etymology on *burgh*. *Like other feminine consonant stems, the Old English burg had vowel change (byrig) in genitive and dative singular, and nominative accusative plural, which survived in dative singular to the 13th cent. This dative, biri, berie, buri, was also at times used for the nominative; whence the modern Bury, -bury, in place-names*

Comment: Also from OED - brough - _[app. a. ON. borg, in sense of ‘wall, enclosure’: cf. the Ger. term hof ‘yard, court, area’, applied to the same phenomenon; the comparison being to the outer wall of a feudal castle. Brough, brugh (brʌx), now in north. Eng. dial. bruff (brʊf), is the northern form; southern forms are burr, and burrow, in Promp. Parv. burwhe. (The word thus appears in origin identical with broch, brough round tower.)]_ It looks like no-one told the northern hordes that vowels were changing and Middlesbrough got stuck (appropriately enough) in the middle ... perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently until the start of the 19th century, it was merely an estate in an area which may have been named after a church in Middleburg.